# Invalid block tag on line 9: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, html, django

I am getting an error with Django where I am attempting to link a second stylesheet to an html document that extends from a base template. The base template has a stylesheet already linked.

Here is the section of the base template:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}?{% now 'U' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        {% block styles %}
        
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
```

And here is the html document that extends from the base template:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
{$ load static %}

{% block title %}
    New Entry
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'encyclopedia/new-entry.css' %}?{% now 'U' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure why the static tag in the second html document is "breaking" the styles block.

I looked into some similar threads but couldn't figure out what I was doing differently, as this appeared to have worked for others.

Comment: there is a $ sing instead of % before your load static in your second html.

Comment: It is `{% load static %}`, not `{$ load static %}`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `$` sign in the html document that extends from the base template:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    New Entry
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'encyclopedia/new-entry.css' %}?{% now 'U' %}">
{% endblock %}
```